# Connection timed out when deploying on Jboss EAP 6.4 using maven plugin

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, web-deployment, maven-plugin

I'm using Jboss EAP 6.4 and I want to use the maven jboss plugin to deploy on Jboss.
But I'm getting this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:undeploy (default-cli) on project MyProject: Could not execute goal undeploy on E:\Work\trunk\MyProject\target\MyProject.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out
```

this is my configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
            <force>true</force>
            <hostname>127.0.0.1/hostname>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
            <port>9990</port>
            <fileNames>
                <fileName>target/MyProject.war</fileName>
            </fileNames>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I was able to log in at the admin jboss console using the password admin and admin (http://127.0.0.1:9990/console)

Comment: it looks strange that `<user>` and `<password>` are defined in `pom.xml` . Normally, these attributes are defined in `~/.m2/settings.xml`, and they are referred to via the `<id>` element

Comment: Means i need to add a server in the settings.xml? can you provide more infos?

Comment: is it like Tomcat to add a server in settings.xml like this                             <servers>

  <server>
   <id>TomcatServer</id>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>password</password>
  </server>

 </servers>

Comment: Mmmh... in the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) I see that you're settings seem to be correct. But it's strange... a password in `pom.xml`

Comment: what if you add `<version>` to your plugin definition?

Comment: there is a typo in <hostname>127.0.0.1/hostname> . "<" is missing

Comment: fixed but still same isseu

Comment: Try port 9999 as 9990 is only http not remoting

Comment: When deploying to a VM or some other "remote" destination, make sure that your firewall allows access, particularly for Windows, see Settings -> Firewall -> Allow an app through the firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On JBoss EAP 6.4 the default native management port is `9999`. The web console uses port `9990` as that is the http management port.

There also is no `fileNames` configuration property. The other properties, with the exception of the `username` and `password` are using the defaults so they shouldn't be required.

The `username` and `password` are also not generally required if you're deploying to localhost. The client should authenticate locally. Of course that does depend on how the server is configured.